# How to open up excel and get workbook without using CreateObject

Tags: excel, winapi, vbscript

For a few reasons discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022266/opening-an-excel-file-manually-allows-formulas-to-run-opening-an-excel-file-wit) I can't open an excel worksheet like this:

```
Set excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = False
Set excelWb = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_path.xls)
```

So I'm trying to open it like this:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "excel.exe"
Wscript.Sleep 5000 ' wait for it to load

Set excel = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
excel.visible = False
Set excelWb = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_path.xls)
```

However, this gives me [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319844) error:

```
ActiveX component can't create object
```

Unless I already have excel opened up, or I open up two pages like so:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "excel.exe"
Wscript.Sleep 5000 

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "excel.exe"
Wscript.Sleep 5000 

Set excel = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
excel.visible = False
Set excelWb = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_path.xls)
```

But this leaves me with one visible excel sheet. And it's sort of weird that I need to open up two in order to use `GetObject`. Any ideas around this?

Comment: Have you tried Sleep 10000? Perhaps the first instance of Excel is taking 7000 to open, and your second call gives it enough time to load properly.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the error. No matter how long I wait, for some reason it only works when two sheets are open.

Comment: I can see how you're ending up with one visible sheet. `GetObject()` is only getting _one_ of your Excel instances and you're then hiding that instance with `excel.visible = False`. But your other instance never gets hidden. If you just `Run` Excel once, but leave it visible, does it appear?

Comment: The reason I'm running excel twice is because if I only run it once it gives me an error, I'd rather not have to open two sheets all together, but if I can hide both that'd be at least a hacky fix.

Comment: If YOU open Excel and then use your VBScript to just do the `GetObject` part, does it work?

Comment: Yeah it does. I'm not sure what the difference is to the `GetObject` between me clicking it open and me opening it through `Run`.

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference. `Shell.Run` behaves the same as launching Excel yourself.

Comment: I agree, hence my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to open the workbook in background, this may be a better option:

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim excel, excelWB
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "excel.exe /e ""C:\Test\blank.xlsx"""
Set excelWB = Nothing
Do
    Set excel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Set excelWB = excel.Workbooks("blank.xlsx")
Loop While excelWB Is Nothing
excel.Visible = False
```

Comment: This has the same result I was struggling with here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022266/opening-an-excel-file-manually-allows-formulas-to-run-opening-an-excel-file-wit