# How to run VBScript GetObject while the computer is locked?

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

For a few reasons discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022266/opening-an-excel-file-manually-allows-formulas-to-run-opening-an-excel-file-wit) I can't open an excel worksheet like this:

```
Set excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_path.xls)
excel.Visible = True
```

So I'm trying to open it like this:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "excel.exe"
WScript.Sleep 5000

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "excel.exe"
WScript.Sleep 5000

Set excel = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
Set workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open( excel_file_path, 3) 
excel.Visible = True
```

This runs just fine when my computer isn't locked. And usually VBScripts can run even when a computer is locked. However, only when the computer is locked, at the line `GetObject(,"Excel.Application")` I get the following runtime error:

```
Error:  ActiveX component can't create object: 'GetObject'
Code:   800A01AD
Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error
```

I tried changing my Windows 7 settings to never lock after some inactivity, but my company's IT department has enforced that setting.

Is there a way to run this script from a locked screen, or is there an alternative you recommend?

Edit:

It has something to do with the way the excel file is being opened... If I open a new blank excel page than lock the screen, `GetObject` will work just fine getting that document, but if I open it using the shell then log out, it won't...

Answer (score 0):

In the section that does not seem to work, add this line after setting visible = TRUE, and see if your calculations then work as expected:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate objExcel.Name
```

Not sure if it will work, but I am doing similar things in some code and this is what's there.
I must have copied or read about it somewhere (wish I could give credit to where).

FYI - I have a vbscript that opens Excel, starts a new workbook, reads a file in as text via a querytable object, then does some automated edits. The code that works for me is:

```
...
set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application") 

' Commented out the following line, so the user can see something is happening.
' objExcel.application.screenupdating   = false  ' Don't update the screen while    shucking and jiving is going on.

objExcel.visible = true
objExcel.application.cursor = 2 ' change cursor to the hourglass.

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate objExcel.Name

' Create a new workbook and worksheet
objExcel.workbooks.add
objExcel.worksheets.add

etc
```

Comment: I appreciate you trying to solve the root of my problem, which is a bewildering one. I gave it a go but unfortunately the same thing, the calculations don't actually run, they just flicker and nothing happens.

Comment: Hmmm, well this was on my mind as I just finished this program the other day.  Good luck!

Comment: Could info from this post help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154434/how-do-you-get-excel-to-refresh-data-on-sheet-from-within-vba

Answer (score 0):

Try the code:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "excel.exe """ & excel_file_path & """"
WScript.Sleep 5000

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "excel.exe"
WScript.Sleep 5000

Set excel = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
```