# Opening an SLK file in powershell with excel does not keep formula

Tags: excel, powershell, office365

I tried to read an SLK file with excel (office 365).
The SLK file has two cells. One contains a "hard coded" value,
and the other contains a formula which is "5+LC(-1)".
By reading the SLK with excel it works fine and I can see the
formula "5+LC(-1)"

Now, I want to do a powershell script for reading this SLK file. Here is what I have done:

```
$FilePath = "C:\tex33.slk"

$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false
$excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = $false
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)

# Print the formula
$workbook.sheets.item(1).activate()
$WorkbookTotal=$workbook.Worksheets.item(1)
$value = $WorkbookTotal.Cells.Item(1, 2).Formula2R1C1Local
$value

$workbook.Close()
```

I expected to see the formula `5+LC(-1)` in the variable `$value`. However, this variable contains the result of this formula and not the formula. Do you know why I don't see the formula in powershell while I can see it on Excel? Note also that, if I do the same thing with an xlsx file instead of the SLK file, all work as expected (`$value` contains the formula).

Do you think this is because I didn't install PI Software as indicated at [Opening an excel file manually allows formulas to run, opening an excel file with VBScript or PowerShell or Python's win32com doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022266/opening-an-excel-file-manually-allows-formulas-to-run-opening-an-excel-file-wit) ? In this case I don't understand why Excel succeed to see my formula while powershell failed.

The SLK file is simple (and you can see the formula 5+RC[-1]) :

```
ID;PMP
F;DG0G10
B;Y1;X2
C;X1;K1
C;X2;E5+RC[-1];K6
W;N1;A1 1;C7 0 7
E
```

Comment: out of curiosity, what do you get when you pipe `$WorkbookTotal.Cells.Item(1, 2).Formula2R1C1Local` to a `Get-Member`?

Comment: I get this: https://pastebin.com/7FPWG26z