# openpyxl 2.4.2: cell value generated by formula empty after saving

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I use openpyxl to open a file, edit some cells and save the changes.
Here's an example:

```
  import openpyxl
  book = openpyxl.load_workbook(sheet_path)    
  sheet = book.active

  for row in range(sheet.max_row):
      index = row + 1
      sheet.cell(row=index, column=1).value = "something"

  book.save(sheet_path)
```

The problem is, when I save the file, other cells are modified. In fact, the cells in my sheet that contains formulas are "corrupted", the file size is greatly reduced and when I use other scripts to read the sheet, the cells containing formulas are reported as empty. But when I open the sheet, everything looks normal and when I save, everything is repaired and the file size is back to normal. I think the problem comes from openpyxl not "calculating" the formulas when saving. This would reduce the file size and require a manual opening/saving in order to get the real cell values. I can't find any way to resolve this issue without completely changing the library I use.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can either have the formulae or the most recently calculated value, never both.

Comment: Please explain: "*...the cells containing formulas are reported as empty.*". This can't be the case, as on file open recompute formulas are done.

Comment: Right after running the script, I use a javascript script that reads cells. I think this script sees the cells as empty because the sheet is open by a script. As I understand, excel recomputes formulas when opened, but the values are not seen by the script since the sheet needs to be saved in order to really keep those values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When openpyxl reads and writes existing formulas, the computed values are omitted, and no values are computed for new formulas.
openpyxl sets a flag in the workbook that tells excel to recompute formula values on load, which is why everything looks normal when you look at it with excel.

Comment: That's what a thought, thanks for the clear answer. Do you know a way to recompute the formulas other that manually opening and saving the sheets?

Comment: If you're running on Windows and have Excel installed, you can use COM automation to open and save the workbook.  A Q&A that has all of the pieces you need is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899215/how-to-wait-until-excel-calculates-formulas-before-continuing-with-win32com - be sure and read the answer b/c the question's code is close but not quite right.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I needed. You just saved me a ton of time :)